# how many incongruent primitive roots does 29 have?

Tags: number-theory

i want to find out how many incongruent primitive roots 29 have. How do i go about finding this?

im not sure how to apporach this problem

Comment: Have you checked this for smaller primes, say $p=11,13,17$ etc. As the total amount of checkings is small you can do that, and try to see a pattern. (Hint: the groups are of even order so if $g$ is a primitive root, $g^2, g^4,g^6. . .$ can't be primitive roots.

Answer (score 2):

If $g$ is a primitive root mod $29$, then every element of $(\mathbb{Z}/29\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ can be written in the form $g^d$ for some integer $d$. Moreover, we can assume that $0\leq d\leq27$ since $g^{28}\equiv 1$ (mod $29$).

What condition on $d$ is needed so that $g^d$ is also a primitive root?

Comment: See Page$\#95$  of http://archive.org/details/NumberTheory_862

Comment: Why is $g^7$ not a generator? Can you find other elements that are not generators?

Comment: $g^7$ is not a generator because $g^7$ has order $4$. $g^d$ is a generator if and only if $d$ is prime to $28$.